# Artistic License 2.0 пояснение для пункта 14

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права, artistic-license

В тексте лицензии [Artistic License 2.0](https://opensource.org/licenses/Artistic-2.0) имеется следующий пункт под номером 14:

> (14) Disclaimer of Warranty: THE PACKAGE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT
>   HOLDER AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS' AND WITHOUT ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
>   WARRANTIES. THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE, OR NON-INFRINGEMENT ARE DISCLAIMED TO THE EXTENT
>   PERMITTED BY YOUR LOCAL LAW. UNLESS REQUIRED BY LAW, NO COPYRIGHT
>   HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTOR WILL BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
>   INCIDENTAL, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
>   OF THE PACKAGE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Объясните как следует понимать данный пункт, особенно про те моменты, где говорится про местное законодательство?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевод:

> (14) Отказ от гарантии: ПАКЕТ ПРЕДОСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ ВЛАДЕЛЬЦЕМ АВТОРСКИХ
>   ПРАВ И НАПАРНИКАМИ "КАК ЕСТЬ" И БЕЗ ЛЮБЫХ ЯВНЫХ ИЛИ ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЕМЫХ
>   ГАРАНТИЙ. ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЕМЫЕ ГАРАНТИИ ТОВАРНОГО СОСТОЯНИЯ, ПРИГОДНОСТЬ
>   ДЛЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЁННОЙ ЦЕЛИ, ИЛИ ОТСУТСТВИЕ ПРАВОВЫХ ПРЕПЯТСТВИЙ ОТРИЦАЮТСЯ
>   ДО РАМОК ВАШЕГО  МЕСТНОГО ЗАКОНОДАТЕЛЬСТВА. ЕСЛИ НЕ ТРЕБУЮТСЯ ЗАКОНОМ,
>   ТО ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ АВТОРСКИХ ПРАВ ИЛИ ЕГО ПОМОЩНИК НЕ БУДУТ ОТВЕТСТВЕННЫ ЗА
>   ЛЮБОЙ ПРЯМОЙ, КОСВЕННЫЙ, СЛУЧАЙНЫЙ ИЛИ ПОБОЧНЫЙ УРОН, ВОЗНИКАЮЩИЙ НА
>   ВЫХОДЕ ПРИ ЛЮБОМ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИИ ДАННОГО ПАКЕТА, ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ ОНИ БЫЛИ
>   УВЕДОМЛЕНЫ О ВЕРОЯТНОСТИ ТАКОГО УРОНА.

1. Гарантий никаких.
2. Если всё же местное законодательство гарантирует какие-либо гарантии, то они появляются у пользователя.
3. Если в процессе использования данного продукта был **понесён ущерб**, то **авторы** данного продукта **будут ответственны за него**, лишь **в случае** явного **требования** этого местным **законодательством**. В остальных случаях авторы не являются ответственными за него.

P.S. Перевод и трактовка вольные, замечания и уточнения приветствуются.